# Is Unity3D (free) sufficient to publish to the Mac App Store?

Tags: unity

Is Unity3 (free) + dev account sufficient to get an app on the MAC app store? Or, do I require the pro version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be fine.  You'll have to do some command line stuff to get it to sign appropriately regardless of pro or free, and that's all documented here: http://technology.blurst.com/unity-games-and-mac-app-store/

Answer (score -4):

I think you need Unity3D Pro + iOS to actually compile any game for iOS

Comment: iOS is the operating system for the iTunes App Store, not the Mac App Store.